# sklearn LogisticRegression and changing the default threshold for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification

I am using LogisticRegression from the sklearn package, and have a quick question about classification. I built a ROC curve for my classifier, and it turns out that the optimal threshold for my training data is around 0.25. I'm assuming that the default threshold when creating predictions is 0.5. How can I change this default setting to find out what the accuracy is in my model when doing a 10-fold cross-validation? Basically, I want my model to predict a '1' for anyone greater than 0.25, not 0.5. I've been looking through all the documentation, and I can't seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is not a built-in feature. You can "add" it by wrapping the LogisticRegression class in your own class, and adding a `threshold` attribute which you use inside a custom `predict()` method.

However, some cautions:

1. The default threshold is actually 0. `LogisticRegression.decision_function()` returns a signed distance to the selected separation hyperplane. If you are looking at `predict_proba()`, then you are looking at `logit()` of the hyperplane distance with a threshold of 0.5. But that's more expensive to compute.
2. By selecting the "optimal" threshold like this, you are utilizing information post-learning, which spoils your test set (i.e., your test or validation set no longer provides an unbiased estimate of out-of-sample error). You may therefore be inducing additional over-fitting unless you choose the threshold inside a cross-validation loop on your training set only, then use it and the trained classifier with your test set.
3. Consider using `class_weight` if you have an unbalanced problem rather than manually setting the threshold. This should force the classifier to choose a hyperplane farther away from the class of serious interest.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, where my false negatives and true negatives are very low.  Is it possible to skew the `z` input in the logit function (sigmoid function) via a parameter,  by making the prob when 'z = 2`  to .5,  instead of  when 'z = 0' being .5? Thank you.

Comment: Is there still no way of changing the decision threshold?

Answer (score 29):

I would like to give a practical answer

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, recall_score, roc_auc_score, precision_score
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(
    n_classes=2, class_sep=1.5, weights=[0.9, 0.1],
    n_features=20, n_samples=1000, random_state=10
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced")
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
THRESHOLD = 0.25
preds = np.where(clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] > THRESHOLD, 1, 0)

pd.DataFrame(data=[accuracy_score(y_test, preds), recall_score(y_test, preds),
                   precision_score(y_test, preds), roc_auc_score(y_test, preds)], 
             index=["accuracy", "recall", "precision", "roc_auc_score"])
```

By changing the `THRESHOLD` to `0.25`, one can find that `recall` and `precision` scores are decreasing.
However, by removing the `class_weight` argument, the `accuracy` increases but the `recall` score falls down.
Refer to the @accepted answer

Comment: when I try this, I get an error `name np is not defined` wht is np?

Comment: `np` is `numpy` : `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the threshold, but it's at 0.5 so that the calculations are correct. If you have an unbalanced set, the classification looks like the figure below.
[image]

You can see that category 1 was very poorly anticipated. Class 1 accounted for 2% of the population.
After balancing the result variable at 50% to 50% (using oversamplig) the 0.5 threshold went to the center of the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention another way to elegantly generate predictions based on scikit's probability computations [using binarize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.binarize.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import binarize

THRESHOLD = 0.25

# This probabilities would come from logistic_regression.predict_proba()
y_logistic_prob =  np.random.uniform(size=10)

predictions = binarize(y_logistic_prob.reshape(-1, 1), THRESHOLD).ravel()
```

Furthermore, I agree with [the considerations that Andreus makes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417912/948768), specially 2 and 3. Be sure to keep an eye for them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok as far as my alghoritm:

```
threshold = 0.1
LR_Grid_ytest_THR = ((model.predict_proba(Xtest)[:, 1])>= threshold).astype(int)
```

and:

```
print('Valuation for test data only:')
    print(classification_report(ytest, model.predict(Xtest)))
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print('Valuation for test data only  (new_threshold):')
    print(classification_report(ytest, LR_Grid_ytest_THR))
```

[image]

Comment: you should combine this answer with your other answer. Alone this doesn't make much sense!

Answer (score 0):

**Special case: one-dimensional logistic regression**

The value separating the regions where a sample `X` is labeled as `1` and where it is labeled `0` is calculated using the formula:

```py
from scipy.special import logit
thresh = 0.1
val = (logit(thresh)-clf.intercept_)/clf.coef_[0]
```

Thus, the predictions can be calculated more directly with

```py
preds = np.where(X>val, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_best_threshold(threshould, fpr, tpr):
   t = threshould[np.argmax(tpr*(1-fpr))]
   # (tpr*(1-fpr)) will be maximum if your fpr is very low and tpr is very high
   print("the maximum value of tpr*(1-fpr)", max(tpr*(1-fpr)), "for threshold", np.round(t,3))
   return t
```

this function can be used if you want find the best True positive rate and nagatuve rate

Comment: To use this you call first `fpr, tpr, threshold = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_scores)` and then `find_best_threshold(threshold, fpr, tpr)`

Comment: that is not what is asking for, we already know wich is the best threshold we just want to add it.