# SciKit learn predict_proba - move threshold from .5 to something else

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to pandas & scikit learn. I've been able to put together a simple model - `Bad` & `Good`

```
df = pd.read_csv('pandas_model.csv', header=None, names=['label', 'resume'])
X = df.resume.astype('U').values
y = df.label

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=1)

vect = TfidfVectorizer()

vect.fit(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)

## create test
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

y_pred_class = logreg.predict(X_test_dtm)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)
# print('LogReg Accuracy Score: ' % str(score))
print(score)
log_reg_cf = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class)
print(log_reg_cf)
```

Confusion Matrix:

```
[[2696  165]
 [ 742  424]]
```

It looks like it is guessing too many data points as "No" when they should be "Yes" (742).

I read that SciKit learn uses the `.5` as the threshold to make a decision from the `predict_proba()` score.

I'm trying to put together  way to "test" various thresholds - ie instead of `.5`, it's `.4`, which will move some of guessed data points from False Negative to being correctly guessed as `Good`.

```
logreg.predict_proba(X_test_dtm)
```

gives me a 2D array of the scores (Bad / Good)

```
array([[0.59946085, 0.40053915], ## guessed as bad, but if the threshold was .6, it would be guessed as good. This is what I'm trying to run simulations on
       [0.89679281, 0.10320719],
       [0.328435  , 0.671565  ],
       ...,
       [0.50415322, 0.49584678],
       [0.84380259, 0.15619741],
       [0.85216752, 0.14783248]])
```

`y_test.head()` gives me the true value (btw, what does 5369 represent? row number?)

```
5369      Bad
11313     Bad
11899    Good
3856      Bad
1961      Bad
```

Ideally I'm trying to run simulations to do something across all of the `X_train_dtm` data:

```
if X_train_dtm[0] (bad score) > .6 (instead of .5):
    then 
        resut = bad
    else
        result = good
```

and then re-check it against `y_test()` and re-check the accuracy score

It doesn't seem like there is anyway to move that `.5` threshold in SciKit learn and looks like I have to do it manually.

Basically trying to make it "harder" for a data point to be guessed as no

Hopefully I've worded this question so it makes sense

I am getting an error from the question marked as a duplicate

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
probs_y=logreg.predict_proba(X_test_dtm)
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, probs_y[:, 0])

ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716241/controlling-the-threshold-in-logistic-regression-in-scikit-learn see the answers there for feedback.

Comment: For your sub-question, `5369 ` represents the index in the original dataset, or the row number if your data was neatly ordered from 0...n. Regarding your main question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52253597/7835267) provides a practical approach to getting your predictions with a different threshold

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the threshold in Logistic Regression in Scikit Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716241/controlling-the-threshold-in-logistic-regression-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you could do it really simply (at least for binary code) with `predict_proba`:

```
probabilities = logreg.predict_proba(X_test_dtm)

threshold = 0.4
good = probabilities[:, 1]
predicted_good = good > threshold
```

This would give you a binary prediction for `good` case if it's probability is higher than `0.5`.

You can easily generalize code above to test any threshold you like with whatever metric you like which requires binary prediction.