# cross validation for logistic regression by setting up threshold probability

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have dataset X_train , y_train , X_test, y_test. Now I want to train logistic regression with K=10 Cross validation . Same time I would like to have F1 score and accuracy for each fold. 
But I would also like to set threshold of probability lets's to .65.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression()
```

How can be done this in single line with sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate or sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Using sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate I can get F1 score for each fold but I want to do it using a threshold probability which i set.

Comment: I pasted the wrong one sorry, I think this is the one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417487/sklearn-logisticregression-and-changing-the-default-threshold-for-classification/52253597

Comment: I think here too I got another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458834/how-is-scikit-learn-cross-val-predict-accuracy-score-calculated . Thanks